# 14.04: Cannot start postgresql service

Tags: 14.04, server, postgresql

I got this issue on starting postgresql. It was working fine yesterday. But all of a sudden it cannot connect. I tried to connect to phppgadmin initially and it did not find servers

So I thought I would start the service. But it fails to do so. This is the command I am using:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

This is the error I get below:

```
LOG:  invalid authentication method "postgres"
CONTEXT:  line 85 of configuration file "/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

And below is the line 85 content:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres           postgres                     peer
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: It reads the second "postgres" as a method of authentication. From the explanation in the file: `METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi", "krb5", "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".` But not "postgres".

Comment: So should I change it to password?

Comment: Go on, try it and see what happens.

Comment: `LOG:  authentication option not in name=value format: peer` That is the error now.

Comment: Ok hey wait I kept it blank and it worked. Thanks a lot !! :)